# Convert const char* to std::string without constructors

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

I always wondered why one can't just convert null-terminated C string into std::string(without constructors, writing helper functions and other workarounds)? It appears to be a simple and overly commonplace problem, where you have, let's say argv[1] null-terminated string as an argument passed to your program(or any other naturally occurred C string) and you need to pass it's value to a function directly.

I.e

How do I wrap the cstr in-place without allocating new string object?

Comment: It seems you should use `std::string_view`.

Comment: That's what a c'tor does, it turns a `const char*` into a `std::string`... Why name it something funny? Your question is unclear. Or are you asking about the need for copy, like S.M. understood?

Comment: I don't think wrapping it in another function actually improves the syntax. Maybe you should give an example of how you use the constructor version.

Comment: yes, `std::string` has a non-explicit constructor taking a `const CharT* s` argument, nothing surprising. Sometimes C++ is straightforward.

Comment: My question is perfectly clear. I very clearly said "without constructor" I want this operation to occur in one line. Just say what to substitute for f, if it's still unclear. You can't substitute two words or two lines of code for it.

Comment: Fine, be stubborn. That's not how one gets help

Comment: @bedbad your question is unclear because it's not clear what you don't understand. You can just remove `f` from your code and it works (by implicitly calling a string constructor). But what's not clear is whether that satisfies your requirement of 'without a constructor'. Do you mean without an explicit constructor call, or do you mean without any constructor of any kind. As you can imagine it's hard to construct a string without using a constructor somewhere.

Comment: If you want to work without constructors, you need to use a different language.

Comment: I don't get what you are asking, but there simply is no way to get an `std::string` object without calling one of its constructors. Period.

Comment: @bedbad - `basic_string` **to** `const char*`. Direction matters

Comment: @bedbad I'm afraid you are wrong, because if you read that error message (maybe take a humility pill at the same time) you will see that it is about converting to `string` to a `const char*` not the other way around.

Comment: @S.M, can you elaborate on string_view please, it's experimental feature.

Comment: `string_view` is not experimental feature, it is already included into C++17. If you are not able to switch to using C++17, you could implement it, it is enough simple. For example chromium sources have own string view class.

Comment: @S.M Well, C++17 is pretty new, so most of the documentation lists it as an experimental feature.

Comment: I'll just ask another question on that because this one is closed within minutes, with the code posted and string_view examples.

Answer (score 4):

This is the answer as best I can tell.

```
const char * cstr = "Hello World.";
...
..myfunc(cstr);
```

Comment: Fwiw, this also calls a constructor. Which is apparently not desired.

Comment: @bedbad The conversion in your error message is not performed in the snippet above. You messed up your MCVE.

Comment: @bedbad The error message you are compaining about come from some other part of your code, not the code I posted above.

Comment: I'll just post complete code, so that there wouldn't be any misunderstanding about it.

Comment: Please redirect to my other question.